# Is Shido a spirit?

Tags: date-a-live

I know Shido has the powers of a spirit, but he wasn't born with them but gained them in some roundabout way.

Does he really qualify as a spirit? Does it have something to do with how Kurumi really wants to devour him?

Answer (score 1):

## Spoiler alert#

Shido was made when Mio Takamiya absorbed Shinji Takamiya into her body.here it is straight from the sight.;

"Shido was born in an attempt by Mio Takamiya to resurrect Shinji Takamiya after he was killed by DEM. By absorbing Shinji's corpse into her own body, Mio planned on reconstructing Shinji as well as bestowing him her powers to ensure that he could become her eternal lover. However, due to the fact that the human body is too frail to withstand Spirit powers, Mio only initially gave Shido one power: the power to gradually seal other powers into his body"

for source go here;https://date-a-live.fandom.com/wiki/Shido_Itsuka

So in a way, he is a spirit.